# How to create a single table using SqlAlchemy declarative_base

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, declarative

To create the `User` table I have to use `drop_all` and then `create_all` methods. But these two functions re-initiate an entire database. I wonder if there is a way to create the `User` table without erasing (or dropping) any existing tables in a database?

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)

    def __init__(self, code=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = name


url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@01.02.03.04/my_db'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)
session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker())
session.configure(bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: Why do you "have to" execute `drop_all` before `create_all`? If there are no other issues, `create_all` should be fine. And you can generally get interested in alembic and migrations.

Comment: [`MetaData.drop_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.drop_all) drops all tables stored in said metadata, not all in DB.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can [create/drop individual tables](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables):

```
User.__table__.drop(engine)
User.__table__.create(engine)
```

Comment: Seems like it is not working using binds. Any idea how to use it? TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish the task:

```
Base.metadata.tables['users'].create(engine)
Base.metadata.tables['users'].drop(engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from app import db
from models import User

User.__table__.create(db.engine)
User.__table__.drop(db.engine)
```